# How to return to OnClickListener from inside a function that gets invoked by a click on Button?

Tags: android, kotlin, button, onclicklistener, buttonclick

I have some lines code that prevents multiple quick click on a button.
If I use that code every time inside `Button.OnClickListener`, it works fine.
But calling the same code every time is not a good idea, so I wanted to keep the code as a global function and call the function when needed.

Here is my code:

```
lastClickTime = 0L
MyButton.setOnClickListener {
     if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1000) {
          return@setOnClickListener
     }
     lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
```

I am trying to make a global method to call from every `Button.OnClickListener`. But I couldn't figure it out what code can replace `return@setOnClickListener`.

```
var lastClickTime = 0L
fun preventMultiQuickClick() {
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1000) {
        //I WANT TO RETURN TO THE button.setOnClickListener 
        //OF THE BUTTON WHICH INVOKES THIS FUNCTION LIKE IN ABOVE CODE
    }
    lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
}


Button.setOnClickListener {
    preventMultiQuickClick()
    //do other stuffs
}
```

How can I achieve this? Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
var lastClickTime = 0L
fun preventMultiQuickClick(): Boolean  {
    return if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1000) {
        false
    }
    lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    true
}


Button.setOnClickListener {
    if(!preventMultiQuickClick()) {
        //do other stuffs
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like that doesn't work. When I click multiple time on the button, it throws exception and the app crashes. The brief detail of the exception is:
`android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`

Comment: I have made an edit to the post, it should work now

Comment: My motto is to create such function as a utility. I am not defining the method inside an Activity or a Fragment. I am creating Kotlin Object and inside it I am defining it, so that I can call it from any Fragment or Activity. So, the problem here is, if I define it in the Object, I can not access activity or runOnUIThread method.